# where command sql query not working

Tags: plugin-development, templating, query, craft2, yii

My problem is that I can't update the specific `$userId`. have the values I've selected. I also get an error:

> Call to a member function where() on integer

I just started to learn Craft. It can be simple for you but not for me.

```
public function updateUserName($userId, $updateUser)
{

    $update = craft()->db->createCommand()->update('contest_user', array(
        'name' => $updateUser))->where('id', $userId);

    return $update;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a look at the [documentation](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCommand#update-detail) the interface for the `update` function is the following.

```PHP
public integer update(string $table, array $columns, mixed $conditions='', array $params=array ())
```

Thus your code should look like:

```PHP
public function updateUserName($userId, $updateUser)
{
    $update = craft()->db->createCommand()->update(
        'contest_user', 
        array('name' => $updateUser), 
        'id=:id',
        array(':id', $userId)
    );

    return $update;
}
```

You can see a working example here:

```PHP
// build and execute the following SQL:
// UPDATE `tbl_user` SET `name`=:name WHERE id=:id
$command->update('tbl_user', array(
    'name'=>'Tester',
), 'id=:id', array(':id'=>1));
```

Comment: Thx. It works. It's so easy when you think about it. I'm just a beginner. So there is plenty of practise to do.